# Selenium IDE: Ignore these errors and go to next step?

Tags: selenium-ide, imacros, kantu

When I run the macro sometimes I get

```
  * [error]

    time out when looking for element 'css=button.btn.btn-primary.col-xs-8.m-0-left.m-md-top.m-0-bottom'

  * [info]

    Test case failed (Runtime 8.86s)
```

====
Is there a way to ignore these errors and go to next step?

Like: if (notFound) go to next step

PS: I am using the Kantu Selenium IDE.